# Strange issue using Git with Visual Studio 2015 and VS Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services as a remote repository. The problem I've encountered is that a file was marked ignored in my local repo, and didn't push to the remote. VS shows `+lessc [add]` under `Included Changes` in VS Team Explorer. If I try to commit, I get an error that there are no changes pending. If I make a change to any file, that file will get committed, and it shows in `Included Changes` alongside `lessc`. No matter what, it doesn't get pushed or committed. If I have to modify the build process I will, but I would like to understand why VS refuses to commit this particular file. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**EDIT 7/17/17:** For anyone viewing this issue, I've moved on from this project and was able to get the file to commit to my repositories by copying it to a different directory and changing the build pipeline to reflect the change.

Comment: The large block of text is very off putting. Try using bullet points and narrowing the problem.

Comment: @MelO'Hagan I apologize for the ugly format. I'll change the question to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .gitignore file in your repo to see if the file is been ignored. Usually, node_modules folder is ignored by default. And you may also need to check the project.json to see if the folder is excluded in it.

By the way, committing "node_modules" folder is no longer recommended. I recommend you to use npm to restore these dependencies before build start.

Comment: I checked the .gitignore, didn't see anything referenced to /bin or lessc. "node_modules" isn't part of the project because the project doesn't use npm to load dependencies. The structure is projectName/tools/Node/less/. The problematic lessc was moved to ./lib/lessc as I believe there was some kind of problem with TFS ignoring "bin" folders. Whenever I work with a Node project, I always add the node_modules folder to the .gitignore. Also, this project isn't ASP.NET 5, it's actually 4.5, so there is no project.json. Thank you for your answer though. It works now after I altered a build step.